# What exception do I catch when the table can't be found in an Entity Framework query using PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, exception, error-handling

I am using Entity Framework with the repository pattern. For each call where I either do

```
_context.Set(entityType).AsQueryable(); //.AsQueryable as an example, could be any other Set method
```

or I make a direct SQL query (add a column, for example):

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("ALTER TABLE " + entityTableName + " ADD " + sqlFieldName + " " + sqlType);
```

I would like to wrap it in a try-catch block. I will try to execute the query, and if it fails because the table for that entity doesn't exist (every entity will have a table), then I would like to catch that exception and then create the table manually. Here is what it would look like:

```
try
{
    return _context.Set(entityType).AsQueryable();
}
catch (Exception) //replace this with specific Exception class
{
    await CreateEntitySqlTableAsync(entityType); //I wrote this method
    return _context.Set(entityType).AsQueryable();
}
```

The problem is I can't find what exception is thrown when the table isn't found (I don't know what specific exception to replace "Exception" in the catch). I know when I was testing this before I got PostgreSQL error 42P01: 'relation "tablename" does not exist', but I don't have access to that test code anymore and it would be a pain to set it up again, so I can't see what exception is thrown. I found [some PostgreSQL documentation with a list of error codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.html). Error 42P01 is under

> Class 42 — Syntax Error or Access Rule Violation

Does this mean I should put SyntaxErrorException (in System.Data) in the catch statement? Is there anyway to be sure that when an error is thrown it is because the table doesn't exist?

Comment: Generally you should catch the exception class that nPgSQL throws - which will be documented in nPgSQL, rather than the postgresql docs. Then check the SQLSTATE in the exception and see if it's `42P01`.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm new to error handling and PostgreSQL and Npgsql. So am I supposed to put `catch(NpgsqlException ex)`, then below `if (ex.ErrorCode == 42P01) //then do something`? The [NpgsqlException class documentation seems fairly vague and lacking](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlException.html), at least for someone who doesn't really understand error handling. Basically I'm not sure how to know that the exception was thrown because the table doesn't exist, and I'm not sure if the NpgsqlException ErrorCode member corresponds to the ErrorCode in Postgres docs